# How can I check for a key in json, which I am getting as an output from RESTful api

Tags: json, groovy, httpbuilder

I have a confusion here with respect to RESTful api.
**Code:**

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject


def isMailer = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://mailer-api.com' )
isMailer.request( GET, JSON ) {
        uri.path = '/is/mail/rest/json/' + token
        isMailer.auth.basic 'ddd', 'aaa'
        headers.'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 Ubuntu/8.10 Firefox/3.0.4'
            response.success = { resp, json ->
                // response handler for a success response code:

                System.out << json

                if(json.has("DISP_NAME")) {
                    println "************************"
                    res = "Yes" 
                } else if (json.has("ListError")) {
                    res =  "No"
                }

            }
        }

        // handler for any failure status code:
        response.failure = { resp ->
            println "Unexpected error: ${resp.statusLine.statusCode} : ${resp.statusLine.reasonPhrase}"
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

**Output w.r.t System.out << json**

```
{
    "DISP_NAME" : "owner-atob",
    "DOM_NAME"  : "mailer",
    "GROUP_ID"  : "1229815",
    "GROUP_NAME"    : "owner-atob"
}
```

**Error w.r.t if(json.has("DISP_NAME"))**

```
No signature of method: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream 
is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [DISP_NAME]
```

**My Problem:**
I want to just check if the key (which is `DISP_NAME` here) is present in json output.
Hence, I want to differentiate my job in if-else block.

Comment: @tim_yates The page no longer exists

Answer (score 15):

Try replacing :

```
if(json.has("DISP_NAME")) {
```

with

```
if( json.DISP_NAME ) {
```

Of course, that won't differentiate between a `NULL` or empty value and a missing value.

To check the field is in the JSON object, just do:

```
if( json.keySet().contains( 'DISP_NAME' ) ) {
```

Comment: I tried using if( json.keySet().contains( 'DISP_NAME' ) ) it says   No signature of method: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.keySet() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Comment: Might be helpful to know what version of groovy/grails you're using  @Amy  , may explain `No Signature` error

Comment: This is useful. I believe that Amy was saying `if (json.containsKey('DISP_NAME'))`